# Old input of select dropdown not restoring after validation fails when using Ajax in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

In create view I have dependent dropdown of "Category" and "Subcategory" it's working as expected but when some validations get failed it didn't restore to previously selected options (Old input).

Create view:

```
<div> 
  <label for="Category">Category</label> 
  <select class="form-control" name="Category" id="CategoryID">
 @foreach ($Category as $key => $value)
  <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value}}</option>
 @endforeach
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="Subcategory">Subcategory</label>
  <select name="Subcategory" class="form-control" id="SubcategoryID">
  <option>Subcategory</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Dependent dropdown:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#CategoryID').on('change', function () {
            var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
            var CategoryID= $(this).val();
            if (CategoryID!= '') {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseurl + '/dropdown' + CategoryID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#SubcategoryID').empty();
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            $('#SubcategoryID').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#SubcategoryID').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have tried getting old input using separate jquery code but it only restores "Category" option but not "Subcategory" option.

To repopulate old select input:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var OldValue = '{{ old('Category') }}';
if(OldValue !== '') {
$('#CategoryID').val(OldValue );
}
});
</script>
```

After validation fails it should restore selected option to its previous state also want to know how to populate saved dependent dropdown data to edit view with same functionality of dependent dropdown to update that record.

Comment: How you submit the form? If you submit the form via server post (submit form), not by ajax then page load after validation failed, you again have to call subcategory ajax function to re-populate the subcategories according to category. Because when page load subcategories function does not run because nothing change happened in dropdown of category and subcategoru does not load on page load. Please share the whole form code.

Comment: Yes, I'm using form submit button with POST method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your subcategory will be load call this $("#CategoryID").change(); 
WHen page will load you are setting value to categoryID dropdown then you've to trigger (categoryID dropdown) cahnge to load the subcategories.

**updated code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var OldValue = '{{ old('Category') }}';
if(OldValue !== '') {
$('#CategoryID').val(OldValue );

// this will load subcategories once you set the category value
$("#CategoryID").change(); 
}
});
```

After subcategories load you can set old subcategory value from old('Subcategory')

**In this way**

replace Your Html select tag line with this
**I've added data attribute with old value whenever your validation fails this will hold your value.**

```
  <select name="Subcategory" class="form-control" id="SubcategoryID" data-selected-subcategory="{{ old('Subcategory') }}>
```

and update subcategories ajax function after subcategories each loop place this line

```
// take subcategory value which has been selected in data attribute 
var subCategoryVal = $("#SubcategoryID").attr("data-selected-subcategory");
if(subCategoryVal !== '')
{
// assign chosen data attribute value to select
$("#SubcategoryID").val(subCategoryVal);
}
```

Now your success function will look like this

```
   success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#SubcategoryID').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        $('#SubcategoryID').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
                    });

// take subcategory value which has been selected in data attribute 
var subCategoryVal = $("#SubcategoryID").attr("data-selected-subcategory");
if(subCategoryVal !== '')
{
// assign chosen data attribute value to select
$("#SubcategoryID").val(subCategoryVal);
}
                }
```

Comment: I will give my feedback after trying your solution also can you please tell me how to fetch saved dropdown values to edit view?

Comment: you want saved (database) value and want to show in subcategory dropdown?

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve both saved values of "Category" and  "Subcategory" for update/modify

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! Waiting for your response on my second doubt.

Comment: If you've saved values (category,subcategory) in database and retrieving, then the same way you've to match the select value with the category value and then call subcategory and assign database subcategory to subcategory. share some code

Comment: Edit stage You've a response of saved data like in $records so you've to set category value like this 

$(document).ready(function() {  var OldValue = '{{ (empty( old('Category') ) ) ? $records['Category'] : old('country') }}';

 if(OldValue !== '') {

 $('#Category').val(OldValue);

 // this will load subcategories once you set the category value

 $("#CategoryID").change();  } });

 When you've subcategories loaded, take subcategory value like above oldvalue variable and assign subcategory value to dropdown like you assign oldvalue to category drop downn by jquery

Comment: Update: In your first solution of validation fail restore value with change() method is not working if there are more than one values in subcategories, eg. If selected CategoryName1 with SubcategoryName2 and submitted form after validation fails it should restore to SubcategoryName2 but it restores to SubcategoryName1... Please take a look

Comment: first solution? talking about answer?

Comment: IN answer when categories loaded after calling change I've write this line
**After subcategories load you can set old subcategory value from old('Subcategory')** But wait I update my answer with explaination of this line with code

Comment: @glitchy I've updated the answer. first I write the line that you've to get value from subcategory but now I explain that line with code that how you will get subcategory selected value. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Tried your solution it retrieves data but on same situation when selecting other category it showing blank subcategory... Please check this GIF for more clarity [link] https://gph.is/g/aXpynnD

Comment: @glitchy the reason was it' not showing the first value because when category changes to Male subcategory value (baby) was not in that list. 
But Now two things here
1- If you change the category and new subcategories dropdown shows then do you want to show first value 
if yes then
2- If you again restore the previous category then you again has to show old value or then start from first one?

Comment: **Replace your If condition code with this **
>> 
if(subCategoryVal !== '') 
{
 // assign chosen data attribute value to select 

$("#SubcategoryID").val(subCategoryVal); 

// remove data attibute value so after change you always get first value if data found 

$("#SubcategoryID").attr("data-selected-subcategory", "");

}

Comment: Yes, now it's working perfectly! showing data in subcategory dropdown, will this also implement in the same way while editing?

Comment: Update: Now old data of subcategory not restoring with $("#SubcategoryID").attr("data-selected-subcategory", "");
Please check this GIF for more clarity [link]https://gph.is/g/4gDNJM7

Comment: @glitchy Please see my comment this. then I update my code. ABove of my this comment  Replace your If co
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247133/old-input-of-select-dropdown-not-restoring-after-validation-fails-when-using-aja/57248187#comment101090398_57248187

Comment: var subCategoryVal = $("#SubcategoryID").attr("data-selected-subcategory"); 
if(subCategoryVal !== '') 
{ 
// assign chosen data attribute value to select $("#SubcategoryID").val(subCategoryVal); 
// if top code does not select any value then show non-empty first value. 
var subCatVal = $("#SubcategoryID").find('option:selected').val();
// check if first value selected is empty mark any first non-empty value.
// checking not to be undefined variale and not to be empty
if(!subCatVal || subCatVal === '')
{ $("#SubcategoryID").find('option:not(:empty)').first().prop('selected',true);}  }

Comment: Above comment if block repalce with answer If block code.For Understanding of top comment for you. If you always want to show first option, coming to original answer, if you noticed when subcategories load it also adds subcategory attribute value to select box.You choose a category Female and then subcategory babY but validation failed and orignal answer will show Female and subcategory babY.But then user again changes the Gender category but this time choose Male and subcategory will load with first empty option. because subcategory attribute vlaue is babY and this is not in Male subcategory.

Comment: success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              $("#SubcategoryID").empty();
              $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $("#SubcategoryID").append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
              });
              var subCatVal = $("#SubcategoryID").find('option:selected').val();
              if (!subCatVal || subCatVal === '') {
                $("#SubcategoryID").find('option:not(:empty)').first().prop('selected',true);
              }
            }
          });
        } else {$("#SubcategoryID").empty();}

Comment: Updated original answer of yours still after validation fails it selecting first value of subcategory.

Comment: @glitchy see my comment and then your comment. You didn't paste all the things which I mentioned.

this line is missing in your code. 
var subCategoryVal = $("#SubcategoryID").attr("data-selected-subcategory");
please again see my comment code

Comment: please tele this has to be there after each loop
var subCategoryVal = $("#SubcategoryID").attr("data-selected-subcategory");     
if(subCategoryVal !== '')  {
$("#SubcategoryID").val(subCategoryVal); 
// if top code does not select any value then show non-empty first value.
var subCatVal = $("#SubcategoryID").find('option:selected').val(); 
 // check if first value selected is empty mark any first non-empty value. // checking not to be undefined variale and not to be empty 
if(!subCatVal || subCatVal === ''){$("#SubcategoryID").find('option:not(:empty)').first().prop('selected',true);}}

Comment: My bad didn't notice! now working perfectly! Awesome!

Comment: Update: In edit view it's not fetching subcategory value, It fetches first record of subcategory, I have tried what you have told:

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    var CatOldValue = '{{ (empty(old('category'))) ? $records['category'] : old('category')}}';
    var SubOldValue = '{{ (empty(old('subcategory '))) ? $records['subcategory '] : old('subcategory ')}}';
if(CatOldValue !== '') {
        $('#CategoryID').val(CatOldValue);
    $('#CategoryID').change();
    }
if(SubOldValue !== '') {
        $('#SubcategoryID').val(SubOldValue);
    $('#SubcategoryID').change();
        }
      });

Comment: Make sure you are setting subcategory value the same way as in add view? Your select dom will be the same as add view, update select attribute as in add view 
>> 
<select name="Subcategory" class="form-control" id="SubcategoryID" data-selected-subcategory="{{ empty(old('Subcategory')) ? records['Subcategory'] : old('Subcategory') }}>

-> then use your subcategory ajax function all as it's you are using in add view. and when you are setting subcategory value right after category in document.ready function it will not work because on that time your subcategory does not load.

Comment: Now it's working! but I have a question without subcategory ajax call how it is working? and without changing in my Create(Add) view select data attribute i.e data-selected-subcategory="{{old('subcategory')}}" , its just working fine just by adding data-selected-subcategory="{{ empty(old('subcategory')) ? $records['subcategory'] : old('subcategory') }}"> in Edit view as you have suggested, How?

Comment: @glitchy the data-attribute is only to keep value, not anything special. 
I user ternary operator simple. old holds all value If validation failed so I keep simple -> If subcategory old value is empty then use database subcategory value else use old subcategry ( validation failed) value.

Comment: Okay, got you now :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one example after doing the validations and you can get the old values securely:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var oldProvince = ( ('{{ old("province") }}' !='') ? '{{ old("province") }}' : '-1');
        var oldDistrict = ( ('{{ old("district") }}' !='') ? '{{ old("district") }}' : '-1');
        alert("pro: "+oldProvince + "dis:"+oldDistrict);
    });
```

If you get `-1` is because the form was sent but didn't selected the subselects.

html code of this two selects:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
       <select class="form-control" id="_province" name="province">
       </select>
       <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
           @foreach ($errors->get('province') as $error)
                {{ $error }}
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <label>Distrito<label style="color:#A83834">* &nbsp;</label></label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
       <select class="form-control" id="_district" name="district">
       </select>
       <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
           @foreach ($errors->get('district') as $error)
                {{ $error }}
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't use braces to output to Javascript in a blade template. What if `old("district")` returns a value with an apostrophe? Use JSON encoding instead. Also, empty strings are considered false, so you can shorten your statement like `var oldProvince = @json(old("province")) || "-1";`